# Why is a 'for' loop faster than a 'while' loop for reading from a file?

Tags: bash, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

#### Preface:

I've always been taught that when working in the shell, it is preferable to do `while` loops over `for` loops, and that you should not use `for` loops with command substitution `cat`'ing a file. My understanding was that there are a number of reasons for this, including:

- A `for` loop requires loading all of the data to be processed into memory all at once
- `for` loops do word splitting on whitespace by default instead of newlines, so in addition to having to have all of your in file in memory, you also have more word splitting going on taking up memory
- `for` loops don't begin processing "to the right of the do" until everything in your `in` statement is done loading, which means that part of the time you're waiting for results, nothing is actually happening while you're "pre-loading".

However, in doing some simple tests, I've found that while memory consumption seems greater in `for` loops (as is expected) the actual performance of `while` loops is lower. It's not a huge difference, and at the scale that this would likely start to matter on any modern machine, I'd probably be switching over to awk or python, but I'm still curious why this is happening.

#### Test setup:

I did a simple series of tests of just echoing lines of a file into /dev/null. My input is two flat files containing 100K and 1Mil IP addresses respectively. In my output below is one test, but I ran this several times with similar results each time. I was running this test on a 2013 MBA (i7, 8g Mem).

#### Test results

```
Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ time for i in $(cat /tmp/ips.100k);do echo $i > /dev/null;done

real    0m1.629s
user    0m1.154s
sys 0m0.480s
Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ time for i in $(cat /tmp/ips.mill);do echo $i > /dev/null;done

real    0m17.567s
user    0m12.414s
sys 0m5.131s
Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ time while read i;do echo $i > /dev/null;done < /tmp/ips.100k

real    0m2.148s
user    0m1.493s
sys 0m0.655s
Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ time while read i;do echo $i > /dev/null;done < /tmp/ips.mill

real    0m21.536s
user    0m14.915s
sys 0m6.617s

Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ tail -5 /tmp/ips.100k /tmp/ips.mill
==> /tmp/ips.100k <==
1.1.134.155
1.1.134.156
1.1.134.157
1.1.134.158
1.1.134.159

==> /tmp/ips.mill <==
1.15.66.59
1.15.66.60
1.15.66.61
1.15.66.62
1.15.66.63

Ds-MacBook-Air:~ d$ wc -l /tmp/ips.100k /tmp/ips.mill
  100000 /tmp/ips.100k
 1000000 /tmp/ips.mill
 1100000 total
```

---

I don't have any direct citations on what I've asserted regarding `for` loops vs `while` loops, but I specifically be it covered in either the ~~TLDP~~ Wooldridge documentation, or another Bash programming guide (some quick googling doesn't yield the exact place where I read most of this years ago.)

Comment: `$(<testfile)` is a more efficient replacement for `$(cat testfile)`, if you're only targeting bash.

Comment: ...by the way, over in freenode's #bash, we tend to warn people away from using documentation from TLDP, particularly the ABS -- while it's not often _completely wrong_, it very frequently demonstrates bad practices leading to bugs. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is more carefully curated and actively maintained documentation.

Comment: Does it matter if you refactor the redirection to `...; done >/dev/null` instead?

Comment: @tripleee I'd expect that to increase performance across-the-board, but not to change the for-vs-while delta (presuming the same transform to the for loop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here is that in the `$(cat testfile)` case you're reading the ENTIRE test file at once into memory and string-splitting it, whereas in the `while read` case you're reading a line at a time.

A smaller number of large reads is more efficient as a matter of course.

There are also bugs introduced by the `$(cat testfile)` approach, which string-splits (which you're aware of) and glob-expands (which you may not be) file contents -- that is to say, if you have a `*`, it can be replaced by a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: To me it seems the number of disk operations is not so important here. If it was, `echo "$(< file)" | while read i` should be close to `for i in $(< file)`. However, I get only a very slight improvement. Although `read` is a built-in, I guess that its repeated execution slows down the loop.

Comment: @Socowi, bigger thing is that `read` reads one byte at a time, so it's a lot of syscalls no matter whether it's reading from a FIFO or a file. (The `echo "$(<file)" |` approach is still doing all those syscalls, just reading from a FIFO from the subshell of bash running the `echo`... but you still pay the context switch penalty).